# Checking for `null` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a little confused by this:

```js
0 > null  // gives me `false`
0 === null // gives me `false` - also
0 == null // is `false`
```

How come `0 >= null` becomes `true`?

Comment: When doing relational comparison between a number and `null`, the latter is coerced to the numeric `0`.

Comment: @Thomas `0 == null` doesn't compare them as strings. `null` is only equal to `undefined` using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons convert null to a number, treating it as 0. That’s why 0 >= null is true.

Example:

```js
0 === Number(null) // true
0 >= Number(null) // true
```

Edit:
There's a difference on how null is handled in comparisons like `>=, <=, >, <` and how it is handled in equality checks like `===, ==` .